# Is there a cross platform C/C++ library that gives us CPU and memory usage stats?

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, cpu-usage, ram

I'm looking to find a C/C++ library that gives me system stats like CPU usage and memory usage.

Is there one that works cross platform?

I just don't want to have to re-invent the wheel (badly).

Comment: Scraping `/proc/self/stat` is probably as close as you will get to "cross-platform".

Comment: @SergeyL., Isn't that Linux specific? What about Windows?

Comment: Comments are not for discussion of closure, please go to meta if you have a complaint or need opinions how to make your question better.

Answer (score 3):

You could use
[SIGAR API](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar)   (C++)

This is an open source library that does basically what your looking for,
but unfortunally there is no platform independent function for this.

If you want one for cross-platforms, ACE has a good one that works for a lot of languages!  Note that ACE abstracts the OS in general, and might be heavyweight for what you want.
[ACE](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/%7Eschmidt/ACE.html)

Comment: Have you used SIGAR? I'm trying to set it up but I'm confused with the build process and then wiki page doesn't really help. After cloning it, what are the exact files that I should compile along with my C++ source to be able to use it? Thanks.